# Flawfinder (CWE-119!/CWE-120) for char array C++

Tags: c++, c++11, security, flawfinder

I have a char array defined like this

```
char buffer[100];
```

When I run `Flawfinder` scan for hits I get the one says:

```
(buffer) char:
  Statically-sized arrays can be improperly restricted, leading to potential
  overflows or other issues (CWE-119!/CWE-120). Perform bounds checking, use
  functions that limit length, or ensure that the size is larger than the
  maximum possible length.
```

I know I have to do the checks when needed to make sure my code will be exceptions free but do we have any way to solve this (define a char array in other ways) and make the `Flawfindr` output without any hit?

**UPDATE**

Here's the full code of the function in case it would help

```
std::string MyClass::randomGenerator(odb::nullable<int> maxLength) {
    
    struct timeval tmnow;
    
    struct tm *tm;
    
    char buf[100];
    
    gettimeofday(&tmnow, NULL);
    
    tm = localtime(&tmnow.tv_sec);
    
    strftime(buf, 100, "%m%d%H%M%S", tm);
    
    string micro = std::to_string(((int)tmnow.tv_usec / 10000));
    
    strlcat(buf, micro.c_str(), sizeof(buf));
    
    std::stringstream stream;
    
    stream << std::hex << stoll(buf);
    
    std::string result(stream.str());
    
    Utilities::find_and_replace(result, "0", "h");
    
    Utilities::find_and_replace(result, "1", "k");
    
    std::transform(result.begin(), result.end(),result.begin(), ::toupper);
    
    if (maxLength) {
        
        return result.substr(result.size() - maxLength.get(), result.size() - 1);
        
    } else {
        
        return result ;
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hitting a single char array like that isn't enough to trigger a warning, do you also have some code that accesses this array? Declaring a dynamic array like std::vector<> just to avoid some warning is overkill when you follow proper coding.

Comment: `std::string`, you know it makes sense.

Comment: I don't think the rest of my code is triggering the warning but I will update the question and add the full code, and you're right with the dynamic array point. @MichaelChourdakis

Comment: Yes, but I need to have it as `char array` @john

Comment: @MazenAk Why? There's rarely a good reason for that.

Comment: Actually, just to maintain the code we have. I'm trying as much as I can to not change the old codes we have. @john

Comment: @MazenAk OK, that is (sometimes) a good reason. But in my experience it is often managers who are reluctant to sanction code changes, while programmers want to make the code as good as possible. But it is a judgement call.

Comment: Indeed, in the end if I couldn't be able to solve this, then I have to refactor the function and make it as good as possible. @john

Comment: @john heap allocations are not cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Flawfinder is really a slightly glorified grep - it's not a true static-analysis tool that does data flow analysis, so I have always taken its output with a healthy dose of salt!

The way you should really write this code is to write true C++ code rather than glorified-C using C runtime functions, which are absolutely subject to memory corruption issues.